# Does anyone know how to pass gradle properties to unit test and override them on command line?

Tags: java, jenkins, junit4, build.gradle

For example, I would like to run smoke tests in Jenkins and the tests will use a different port/address depending on the environment.  So I want to set a default value somewhere (gradle.build?) and then be able to override it on the gradle command line.  But I need to use the default or overridden value in my junit test. Right now I'm just reading a properties file in my junit test to get the url but I want to use it somehow from gradle.build value.

Right now I just use property file.

```
@Before
public void setup() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream("gradle.properties"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        logger.debug("Error loading gradle.properties",e);
    }
}

@Test 
public void testResponseCode () {   
    get(props.getProperty("url") + HISTORIC).then().assertThat().statusCode(equalTo(200));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to pass it *through* Gradle as a system property, i.e. `-Dkey=value`. Alternatively, your Gradle script could set a system property, e.g. `System.properties.'my.property' = ?`. A JUnit test will have no access to Gradle properties.

Comment: Turns out that's easy in Gradle: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/passing-system-property-user-home-to-junit-test-classes-not-working-for-me/6504/3